# aspect ratio is not working properly inside flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, hyperlink, aspect-ratio

So I have a bunch of links in a flex container and want them to be squares. I've set aspect ratio for all of them of `1 / 1` and added a padding block of 1rem.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.link {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-block: 1rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <a class="link" href="#">1</a>
  <a class="link" href="#">2</a>
  <a class="link" href="#">3</a>
</div>
```

But this isn't working the links are not squares at all. The width changes when i change the padding block, so there's something happening because of the aspect-ratio property, but the links still aren't squares.

Also, I've made some tests and when the content inside the element with `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;` grows in height, the aspect ration doesn't work, the width doesn't change.

You can see these tests in [a pen I created](https://codepen.io/rafaeldevvv/pen/GRePaZj).

Is there a way i can make my links squares regardless of their contents' height?

Comment: I got an improvement, when setting an explicit `width` in `vw` or `%`. 

Comment: I believe that it's not a bug, since it's the same in FF and Chrome. And it's determined in https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#aspect-ratio-automatic . But good God I couldn't understand that text

Answer (score -1):

If you consider the inline padding and `box-sizing: border-box` it should work fine.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.link {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-inline: 1rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <a class="link" href="#">1</a>
  <a class="link" href="#">2</a>
  <a class="link" href="#">3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems not to work. I edited the example provided by the OP, checked there